# Trying to figure out why my Azure website stopped serving pages

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I built a test wordpress site in Azure yesterday and while I was playing around with it today it stopped serving pages.  The dashboard reads that everything is up and running but only a blank page is being served.  The URL is http://perryrubber.azurewebsites.net/

I have looked at some of the FTP logs, but nothing is popping out at me as to what is causing this.  What can I look at to start debugging this?

Comment: Hi, can you tell me exactly what "playing around" included? Did you update any plugins? add any new pages? etc.

Comment: I added a theme, installed some plugins, created a child theme, and edited some of the values of said themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if there is a .maintenance file in the root. If so remove it.

Other than that it most likely has something to do with either the theme or plugin that was installed. If you are able to access the dashboard I would try to uninstall the latest item to see if it makes any difference

Comment: One more thing to try is to restart the site by going here http://perryrubber.scm.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: There is no .maintenance file in the wwwroot folder in the ftp site.  Is there a location for a log that might point to what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed? If so you can connect right to it through server explorer and look at the logs. Instructions can be found here as well https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#webserverlogs

Comment: I've looked through logs, and narrowed it down to my 'child theme' but any help you could offer in further narrowing down the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: No, that is my primary problem.  When it fails it just sends blank pages.  And it is very odd....it takes 10-15 minutes after the change for the blank pages to start occurring.